# get all Timers expunged ( Payara, Programmatically )

Tags: jakarta-ee, timer, ejb, payara

I can't find a way to monitor the expunge of the timers in Java EE, is there a way to track when a timer has been expunged after failed delivered?
In my case, scanning the application server log is not a possible way.

(Ideally something given by payara or that generally works for all the projects deployed)

Many thanks